# Java 9 JavaFX Preloader

Tags: java, javafx, java-9, preloader, javafx-9

In Java 8 I can launch a JavaFX application with a preloader using the following method:

```
LauncherImpl.launchApplication(WindowMain.class, WindowMainPreloader.class, 
new String[]{...});
```

I prefer to start it from code, like above, instead of using a deploy configuration, because I don't want the graphical interface to start every time I start the application, but only after some code that has computed that the application should run in GUI mode.

I was using the class "com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl", but apparently in Java 9 all classes starting with "com.sun" are removed. So, how can I start the application with the preloader in Java 9?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a custom loading screen in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361225/how-to-create-a-custom-loading-screen-in-javafx)

Comment: JavaFX has a native API for preloaders, see my simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74279131/10686802

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a comment on the answer to this question:

[How to create splash screen as a Preloader in JavaFX standalone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882784/how-to-create-splash-screen-as-a-preloader-in-javafx-standalone-application)

> system property `javafx.preloader=classname` seems to work too.

I didn't try it, but perhaps you could try setting that property and just launching your main app via the public [`Application.launch(appClass, args)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) API and perhaps the preloader will launch first.

Looking into the code for `Application.launch`, it seems that this would work.  Here is the code which is eventually invoked, copied from the Java 8 source:

```
public static void launchApplication(final Class<? extends Application> appClass,
        final String[] args) {

    Class<? extends Preloader> preloaderClass = savedPreloaderClass;

    if (preloaderClass == null) {
        String preloaderByProperty = AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<String>) () ->
                System.getProperty("javafx.preloader"));
        if (preloaderByProperty != null) {
            try {
                preloaderClass = (Class<? extends Preloader>) Class.forName(preloaderByProperty,
                        false, appClass.getClassLoader());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.printf("Could not load preloader class '" + preloaderByProperty +
                        "', continuing without preloader.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    launchApplication(appClass, preloaderClass, args);
}
```

So you should be able to launch an app with a preloader using:

```
System.setProperty("javafx.preloader", "my fully qualified preloader class name");
Application.launch(myMainClass, args);
```

Answer (score 3):

from jdk 9, LauncherImpl not work [jdk 10 - java.graphics module-info.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0aCr.jpg)

all classes in package `com.sun.javafx.application` exported to special modules `(java.base,javafx.controls,javafx.deploy,javafx.swing,javafx.web)`,

So if you add module `(javafx.graphics)` in your module its not work,

so use : `System.setProperty("javafx.preloader",path_class_loader)` as an alternative to `LauncherImpl` for `jkd 9` and above

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, this solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

**JDK 8:**

```java
LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Main.class, Preloader.class, arguments);
```

**JDK 9:**

```java
System.setProperty("javafx.preloader", Preloader.class.getCanonicalName());
    Application.launch(Main.class, arguments);
```