# JavaFX application does not compile well when using LauncherImpl instead Application

Tags: java, javafx, graalvm, gluonfx

I have a JavaFX application which compiles to native using GluonFx plugin.
I want to add a Preloader to show when starting. I managed it by changing the initialization from:

`Application.launch(MainView.class, args)` to `LauncherImpl.launchApplication(MainView.class, MyPreloader.class, args)`

The compilation process executes till the end with no errors, but the app doesn't boot.
If I try to run the agent (mvn gluonfx:runagent) I have the following error:
`cannot access class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.application to unnamed module`

Someone knows how to solve this, or what other way can I use to load my Preloader?

PS: Running from the IDE works. The problem is after compilation to native

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by using the answer in this ticket:

[Java 9 JavaFX Preloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533370/java-9-javafx-preloader)

Replaced:
`LauncherImpl.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(MainView.class, MyPreloader.class, args)`

by

```
System.setProperty("javafx.preloader", MyPreloader.class.getCanonicalName());
Application.launch(MainView.class, args);
```